# Why wont collide_rect work in this scenario? The game keeps printing "Collided!" even when the two sprites aren't touching?

Tags: python, class, pygame

This is a snake remake. My goal here was to make the apple respawn randomly after the snake collided with it. For some reason the collide_rect function seems to think they are continuously colliding at all times after I start the game.

Any other tips to help clean this mess up are also welcome:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

WHITE = (pygame.Color("white"))
BLACK = (  0,   0,  0)
RED   = (245,   0,  0)
TURQ  = (pygame.Color("turquoise"))
GREEN = (  0, 155,  0)
GREY  = ( 90,  90, 90)
SCREEN = (800, 600)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN)
#Set the window title and picture
pygame.display.set_caption('Block Worm')
ICON = pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")

pygame.display.set_icon(ICON)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 20
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
APPLE_SIZE = 10
TINY_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 15)
SMALL_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 25)
MED_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 50)
LARGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 75)
HUGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 150)
IMG = pygame.image.load("snakehead.png")
APPLE_IMG = pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")
DIRECTION = "up"    

def pause():
    paused = True
    message_to_screen("Paused",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = -100,
                      size = "huge")
    message_to_screen("Press C to continue or Q to quit.",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = 25)
    pygame.display.update()
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_c, pygame.K_p):
                    paused = False
                elif event.key in(pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        CLOCK.tick(5)

def score(score):
    text = SMALL_FONT.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [0, 0])

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    intro = False
                if event.key in (pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_to_screen("Welcome to",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -170,
                          size = "large")
        message_to_screen("Block Worm",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                          size = "huge")
        message_to_screen("The objective of the game is to eat apples.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 36,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("The more apples you eat the longer you get.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 68,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("If you run into yourself or the edges, you die.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 100,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("Press C to play or Q to quit.",
                          GREY,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 210,)
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "tiny":
        TEXT_SURFACE = TINY_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "small":
        TEXT_SURFACE = SMALL_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        TEXT_SURFACE = MED_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        TEXT_SURFACE = LARGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "huge":
        TEXT_SURFACE = HUGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    return TEXT_SURFACE, TEXT_SURFACE.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg, color, Y_DISPLACE = 0, size = "small"):
    TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    TEXT_RECT.center = (SCREEN[0] / 2), (SCREEN[1] / 2) + Y_DISPLACE
    gameDisplay.blit(TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT)

class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, size, trail, start_size):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.size = size
        self.trail = trail
        self.start_size = start_size
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        if DIRECTION == "right":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 270)
        elif DIRECTION == "left":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 90)
        elif DIRECTION == "down":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 180)
        else:
            HEAD = image
        gameDisplay.blit(HEAD, (self.trail[-1][0], self.trail[-1][1]))
        for XnY in self.trail[:-1]:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, GREEN, [XnY[0], XnY[1], self.size, self.size])

class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.size = self.rect.width
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (100, 100))

    def random_location(self):
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[0] - 10), 10)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[1]- 10), 10)
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))





def gameLoop():
    global DIRECTION
    DIRECTION = "up"
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    SCORE = 0

    player_snake_trail = [] # Where the snake head has been.
    enemy_snake_trail = [] # If I create an AI snake.
    start_length = 1

    lead_x = (SCREEN[0] / 2)
    lead_y = (SCREEN[1] - (SCREEN[1] / 5))
    move_speed = 10
    move_speed_neg = move_speed * -1
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = -move_speed

    while not gameExit:
        if gameOver == True:
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              RED,
                              Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                              size = "huge")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit.",
                              BLACK,
                              Y_DISPLACE = 50,
                              size = "small")
            pygame.display.update()
        while gameOver == True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameOver = False
                        gameExit = True
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a):
                    lead_x_change = move_speed_neg
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "left"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d):
                    lead_x_change = move_speed
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "right"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w):
                    lead_y_change = move_speed_neg
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "up"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s):
                    lead_y_change = move_speed
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "down"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_p, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pause()

        # If the snake goes beyond the screen borders the game will end.
        if lead_x >= SCREEN[0] or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= SCREEN[1] or lead_y <0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

        # Draw the apple on screen
        red_apple = Apple(APPLE_IMG)

        # Draw the snake on screen
        SNAKE_HEAD = []
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(lead_x)
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(lead_y)
        player_snake_trail.append(SNAKE_HEAD)
        # If you hit yourself, game over.
        if SNAKE_HEAD in player_snake_trail[:-1]:
           gameOver = True
        if len(player_snake_trail) > start_length:
            del player_snake_trail[0]

        player_snake = Snake(IMG, 10, player_snake_trail, start_length)
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player_snake, red_apple) == True:
            print("Collided!")

##            start_length += 1
##            SCORE += 1
##            red_apple.random_location()

        # If the snake eats the apple
        # Old code below, needs to be rewritten. Disregard.
##        if APPLE_RECT.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y) == True:
##            randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()
##            start_length += 1
##            SCORE += 1

        score(SCORE)

        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

Comment: Why are you drawing the sprites in the init methods? I think you need to look at how to use sprites properly. Create them once and use the `update()` function to move them around and the draw() to blit them.

Comment: Should you be calling random_location() in the Apple constructor? Also, this is a LOT of code. You should post less if you expect people to actually be able to help you.

Comment: You should simplify your code to make it easier for people to help you. Also, simplifying your code may help you understand where it has gone wrong.

Have you tried printing out the coordinates of the objects when you detect a collision? That should be your first debugging step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the rects in the constructors for the apple and snake head, they have x and y co-ordinates of 0.  You need to set the rects and update them as the snake moves.  I have added a set_rect method to them.  I have also moved the draw from apple.random_location to its own method.  Your code should look like this:

```
init()
run()
```

and in run:

```
check_events()
update_snake()
collision_check()
draw_things()
clock.tick(FPS)
```

Here is the altered code, try to break it up into sections as above.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

WHITE = (pygame.Color("white"))
BLACK = (  0,   0,  0)
RED   = (245,   0,  0)
TURQ  = (pygame.Color("turquoise"))
GREEN = (  0, 155,  0)
GREY  = ( 90,  90, 90)
SCREEN = (800, 600)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN)
#Set the window title and picture
pygame.display.set_caption('Block Worm')
ICON = pygame.Surface((10,10)) #pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")

pygame.display.set_icon(ICON)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 20
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
APPLE_SIZE = 10
TINY_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 15)
SMALL_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 25)
MED_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 50)
LARGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 75)
HUGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 150)
IMG = pygame.Surface((10,10)) #pygame.image.load("snakehead.png")
APPLE_IMG = pygame.Surface((10,10)) #pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")
DIRECTION = "up"    

def pause():
    paused = True
    message_to_screen("Paused",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = -100,
                      size = "huge")
    message_to_screen("Press C to continue or Q to quit.",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = 25)
    pygame.display.update()
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_c, pygame.K_p):
                    paused = False
                elif event.key in(pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        CLOCK.tick(5)

def score(score):
    text = SMALL_FONT.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [0, 0])

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    intro = False
                if event.key in (pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_to_screen("Welcome to",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -170,
                          size = "large")
        message_to_screen("Block Worm",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                          size = "huge")
        message_to_screen("The objective of the game is to eat apples.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 36,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("The more apples you eat the longer you get.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 68,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("If you run into yourself or the edges, you die.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 100,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("Press C to play or Q to quit.",
                          GREY,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 210,)
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "tiny":
        TEXT_SURFACE = TINY_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "small":
        TEXT_SURFACE = SMALL_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        TEXT_SURFACE = MED_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        TEXT_SURFACE = LARGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "huge":
        TEXT_SURFACE = HUGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    return TEXT_SURFACE, TEXT_SURFACE.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg, color, Y_DISPLACE = 0, size = "small"):
    TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    TEXT_RECT.center = (SCREEN[0] / 2), (SCREEN[1] / 2) + Y_DISPLACE
    gameDisplay.blit(TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT)

class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, size, trail, start_size):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.size = size
        self.trail = trail
        self.start_size = start_size
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        if DIRECTION == "right":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 270)
        elif DIRECTION == "left":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 90)
        elif DIRECTION == "down":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 180)
        else:
            HEAD = image
        gameDisplay.blit(HEAD, (self.trail[-1][0], self.trail[-1][1]))
        for XnY in self.trail[:-1]:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, GREEN, [XnY[0], XnY[1], self.size, self.size])

    def set_rect(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect

class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.random_location()
        self.size = self.rect.width
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (100, 100))

    def random_location(self):

        x = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[0] - 10), 10)
        y = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[1]- 10), 10)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y, 10, 10)
        print "apple rect =",
        print self.rect

    def draw(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))




def gameLoop():
    global DIRECTION
    DIRECTION = "up"
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    SCORE = 0

    player_snake_trail = [] # Where the snake head has been.
    enemy_snake_trail = [] # If I create an AI snake.
    start_length = 1

    lead_x = (SCREEN[0] / 2)
    lead_y = (SCREEN[1] - (SCREEN[1] / 5))
    move_speed = 10
    move_speed_neg = move_speed * -1
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = -move_speed


    red_apple = Apple(APPLE_IMG)

    while not gameExit:
        if gameOver == True:
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              RED,
                              Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                              size = "huge")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit.",
                              BLACK,
                              Y_DISPLACE = 50,
                              size = "small")
            pygame.display.update()
        while gameOver == True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameOver = False
                        gameExit = True
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a):
                    lead_x_change = move_speed_neg
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "left"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d):
                    lead_x_change = move_speed
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "right"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w):
                    lead_y_change = move_speed_neg
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "up"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s):
                    lead_y_change = move_speed
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "down"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_p, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pause()

        # If the snake goes beyond the screen borders the game will end.
        if lead_x >= SCREEN[0] or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= SCREEN[1] or lead_y <0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

        # Draw the snake on screen
        SNAKE_HEAD = []
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(lead_x)
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(lead_y)
        player_snake_trail.append(SNAKE_HEAD)

        # draw the apple on the screen
        red_apple.draw()

        # If you hit yourself, game over.
        if SNAKE_HEAD in player_snake_trail[:-1]:
           gameOver = True
        if len(player_snake_trail) > start_length:
            del player_snake_trail[0]

        player_snake = Snake(IMG, 10, player_snake_trail, start_length)
        player_snake.set_rect(pygame.Rect(lead_x, lead_y, 10, 10))

        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player_snake, red_apple) == True:
           print("Collided!")

           start_length += 1
           SCORE += 1
           red_apple.random_location()

        # If the snake eats the apple
        # Old code below, needs to be rewritten. Disregard.
##        if APPLE_RECT.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y) == True:
##            randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()
##            start_length += 1
##            SCORE += 1

        score(SCORE)

        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```